# cs107 makefile::cannot find -lrssnews

Tags: c, makefile

I am want to begin working on the 4th assginment, RSS searcher, of Online Stanford CS107 Programming Paradigms course. However, I am lagging at the very first step; I can not compile the prepared, to-work-on, unfinished program.

I get this error when I type make;

```
gcc rss-news-search.o -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function -g  -lnsl -lrssnews -L/media/D/Programming/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/ -o rss-news-search
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrssnews
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:32: recipe for target 'rss-news-search' failed
make: *** [rss-news-search] Error 1
```

I have installed libexpat-dev.
Here is the link to the course, its the 4th programming assignment, RSS;
https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS107

Thanks in advance

Comment: As the error states, you're missing a library called `rssnews`, so you should install it somehow or check that the compiler can find it if it's already installed.

Comment: A quick note, the link is broken. but @ForceBru is right

Comment: Yes, and the project comes with a file named librssnews.a But I dont know what to do with it to say the truth @ForceBru

Comment: Thank you @mame98. I updated the links

Comment: Put `librssnews.a` in `/media/D/Programming/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/`. You may also have to swap the arguments: `-L/media/D/Programming/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/ -lrssnews`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That the project comes with `librssnews.a` is good news. This file is a *static library* called `rssnews` and this is what you need to compile the project successfully!

*Warning: you almost certainly don't need to follow these steps, go on reading to see why.*

1. Put this file in your project's directory (the one you're running the build from) or in the `lib` directory, if the project contains one (if it doesn't, *don't* create one).

   Run the build again. If it fails with the same error, go on to next steps.
2. Find out where the compiler normally looks for libraries by compiling a simple code with the `-v` flag. For example, `gcc simple.c -v`. You'll get tons of output that will contain the paths the compiler visited to link your program.

   Copy the library file to one of these paths and run the build once again.

Given that the library search path is specified explicitly, you can simply put the library into `/media/D/Programming/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/` and skip the steps discussed earlier altogether. But if it wasn't, you'd probably have to follow them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still get the same error @ForceBru.

Comment: I did move this librssnews.a to /usr/include(this dir is searched by gcc when I followed your steps). But one question I have; shouldnt I edit the makefile? bcs its preconfigured for their PCs at the university. And gcc says it cant find "lrssnews" not "librssnews.a", why is this?

Comment: @tdm3732, the italicized text in my answer says to move the file to `/media/...` as this is the directory specified in the Makefile. Any file called `lib<something>.[a|lib|dylib]` is treated as a library file that contains a library called `<something>`, so `lib` and the extension are omitted. One requests the compiler to tell the linker to link with this library by passing the argument `-l<something>`.