# C Makefile - Cannot find library -lrssnews

Tags: c, makefile

I have reviewed the answer provided [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245566/cs107-makefilecannot-find-lrssnews) but I still cannot seem to make progress.

I am attempting to follow along with the online Stanford course [CS107](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS107). I was able to complete assignments 2-3 but am stuck on assignment number 4.

I receive this error when I type "make" in the command line.

> gcc -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function    -c -o rss-news-search.o rss-news-search.c
> gcc rss-news-search.o -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function -g  -lnsl -lrssnews -L/home/pi/Desktop/C/StanfordHW/Assn4/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/ -o rss-news-search
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrssnews
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [Makefile:32: rss-news-search] Error 1

Here is the snippet of my Makefile:

> CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function $(DFLAG)
>
> LDFLAGS = -g $(SOCKETLIB) -lnsl -lrssnews -L/home/pi/Desktop
> /C/StanfordHW/Assn4/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/$(OSTYPE)
>
> PFLAGS= -linker=/usr/pubsw/bin/ld -best-effort

So, I tried doing what the previous answer suggested by moving the file "librssnews.a" to the folder /lib from where I am executing the make command. But this did not work.
[Here is an image of my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omhIL.png)

Is there something else that I can try? Please excuse any obvious mistakes, as I'm still learning. Thank you.

Comment: There is a `-L/media/D ...` flag, so you might just try putting the `librssnews.a` file in `/media/D/Programming/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I apologize, my mistake - I had copied the error from the previous post, and I missed that part. I don't have that flag in my own error. I updated the error message to reflect what I'm seeing on my raspberry pi. Sorry again, thanks for commenting though.

Comment: Your Makefile has an `$(OSTYPE)` variable that appears to be empty.  What build system are you using?  Perhaps that should is being set directly in the `Makefile` with a call to `uname` or similar.  But unless this is a course on build systems, it seems they ought to provide you with  some packages.  Is there a `-devel` rpm or deb package you are supposed to install?